# Laravel validate current date against database date using carbon

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I'm creating a schedule function where i validate a date field in a table against the current date, if the date is past then i want to update the second column with '3224407' . the field type fecha_vigencia is date.

my schedule function is :

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function(){

     foreach(Equipo::all()  as $equipo){

          $fecha_vigencia= Carbon::parse($equipo->fecha_vigencia);

          if($fecha_vigencia->isPast())
            {
              DB::table('equipo')->update(['telefono_contacto' => '3224407']);
            }
          }

}
```

now my database records before running schedule:run :
  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxJ6B.jpg)

most of the date fields in the fecha_vigencia column are in the future "2017-08-15",
as displayed on the image above, when i compare against the current date-> "2017-07-31" ,using $fecha_vigencia->isPast(), all fields on the Telephone column are updated. only should update 1 field with date 2017-07-10 instead.
what's wrong with the function?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely wanted something like this

```php
$equipo->telefono_contacto = '3224407';
$equipo->save();
```

instead of

```php
DB::table('equipo')->update(['telefono_contacto' => '3224407']);
```

Right now you're effectively updating the whole table each time `$fecha_vigencia->isPast()`.

Comment: you're 100% right, I had not noticed i was updating the whole table .